# bind an object by ref to fancytree source, is possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, fancytree

i want to bind an object to the fancytree source by reference, so that when i change any property in that object will suddenly reflect on the tree

```
var data = [
    {title: "Node 1", key: "1"},
];

$("#tree").fancytree({
    autoCollapse: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    checkbox: true,
    selectMode: 3,
    source: data
});
```

is this possible with fanytree ?

i tried with this code(given below) but fail

```
    data = [{title: "Node 10", key: "1"}];

    ($("#tree").fancytree("getTree")).reload().done(function(){
        alert("reloaded");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

```
data = [{title: "Node 10", key: "1"}];

($("#tree").fancytree("getTree")).reload(data).done(function(){
    alert("reloaded");
});
```

I.e. pass the new data to reload()?